# missing client token vault docker

Tags: c#, docker, hashicorp-vault

I use vault docker with the following Docker env file:

```
#Vault 
VAULT_IMAGE=vault:latest
ROOT_TOKEN=testroottoken
ROLE_ID=testRole
secret_id=testsecret
```

and am trying using the default apis like this

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {

                var responseMessage = client.PostAsync(
                        $"http://localhost:8200/v1/auth/approle/login ",
                        CreateByteArrayContent(objectToBeCreated, "application/json"))
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();

                var response = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


                if (responseMessage.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
```

I use the same approach for a hosted vault, but locally it gives bad request missing client token. if someone can help me solve this please

Answer (score 0):

You need to send "X-Vault-Token" in the header. To check the sanity of the generated token you can follow these steps:

1.Navigate to the path where you have the Vault binary

> C:\Users>stack cd C:\Users\stack\Desktop

2. Set the VAULT_ADDR environment variable

> C:\Users\stack\Desktop>set VAULT_ADDR=vault_url

3. Login to Vault using ID, Password and Vault namespace to generate a VAULT_TOKEN

> C:\Users\stack\Documents\Softwares\Vault>vault login -ns=namespace
>   -method=id username=stack

Password (will be hidden):

```
Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below
is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login"
again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.
     

Key                    Value
---                    -----
token                  <token generated>
token_accessor         <token accessor value>
token_duration         1h
token_renewable        true
token_policies         ["default"]
identity_policies      []
policies               ["default"]
token_meta_username    stack
```

4. Set the VAULT_TOKEN as the environment variable.

> C:\Users\stack\Desktop>set VAULT_TOKEN = generated in step3